# Web3.js contract call: Provider does not have a request or send method to use

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, web3-providers, function

Unfortunately, the very few similar questions either have outdated answers or solutions that did not work in my case.

I'm getting the following error when calling a function in an Aave Smart Contract:

> Provider does not have a request or send method to use.

I have a first button that connects to Metamask (works well, I am able to get my balance etc..)

```
const loadWeb3 = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {

        await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
        let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

      
    } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
        window.alert('Non-ethereum browser detected.')
    }
}
```

Then, another button calls the approve function of Aave's smart contract. It fails at 'contract.methods.approve'.

```
 async function approveWeb3(e, depositValue) {
    //await window.ethereum.enable();
    //depositValue is for example: 0.5 (in this case, the unit is MATIC)

    let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

    e.preventDefault();
    
    let assetAddress = MUMBAICONTRACT.MATICTestnet //token address on Mumbai Testnet

    try {
        let weiValue = web3.utils.toWei(depositValue.toString(), 'ether');

        var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
        var contract = new Contract(CONTRACT.abiERC, MUMBAICONTRACT.MumbaiPoolSmartContractAdress);
        contract.methods.approve(MUMBAICONTRACT.MumbaiPoolSmartContractAdress, weiValue).send({from: account[0]})

        } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        }

}
```

Any idea why I get this error? I've been struggling with this in the last days unable to find a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure that Metamask is connected to "Mumbai Testnet" when you interact with the contract.
- Make sure you await to async commands.
- Validate that `account[0]` is valid.

Also, I believe your contract needs to be connected to the provider, try creating the contract with the web3 variable you initialised:

```
new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])
```

Comment: Thanks.

- I am correctly connected to the Mumbai Testnet.
- account[0] is valid (it is a string with the wallet address)

Could it be linked to the await-async command? I tried modifying the following line but it returns the same error:
        await contract.methods.approve(MUMBAICONTRACT.MumbaiPoolSmartContractAdress, weiValue).send({from: account[0]})


Any other idea how I could handle this?

Comment: @Clement Edited my answer

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot. For reference, I changed the line "var contract = new Contract(..." for "var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(..."

Comment: @Clement can you please mark as answer? Happy to help